# Braintree payment gateway - Get customer's subscriptions details

Tags: payment-gateway, braintree, subscription

I am using Braintree payment gateway in my Rails application. I am wondering if I can retrieve the customer's subscriptions details from it. According to the documentation, one of the way of doing this is `subscription = Braintree::Subscription.find(id)`

When creating a subscription, basic objects such as `plan_id` and `amount` was saved into the database. So, how do I retrieve subscription's information such as `next_billing_date` that is associated to the customer?

Comment: Isn't next_billing_date one of the attributes of the subscription object returned from find() and create() ?

Comment: Yea it is. But how do I return the `next_billing_date` from the gateway since it's not in my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Assuming you have a subscription ID:

```
# Find the subscription
subscription = Braintree::Subscription.find(sub_id)

# Access the subscription's next billing date
subscription.next_billing_date
```

[`Braintree::Subscription.find()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/find/ruby) returns a [`Braintree::Subscription` result object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/subscription/ruby#next_billing_date).

#### Assuming you have a customer ID:

```
# Find the customer
customer = Braintree::Customer.find(cust_id)

# Retrieve the customer's first payment method
pm = customer.payment_methods.first

# Retrieve the subscriptions created with that payment method
subscriptions = pm.subscriptions

# Access the subscription's next billing date
subscriptions.first.next_billing_date
```

[`Braintree::Customer.find()`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/find/ruby) returns a [`Braintree::Customer` response object](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/ruby). The customer's [payment methods can then be retrieved](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/customer/ruby#payment_methods). Subscriptions are associated to payment methods. Once you have a payment method, you can retrieve [an array of `Braintree::Subscription` objects](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/ruby#subscriptions).

Comment: After retrieving the for example `subscription.next_billing_date`, how do I display it to user on the html because the `next_billing_date` is not in my database.

Comment: That is a separate question. I recommend starting a new question if you can't find the answer through research.